# as_kable_extra removes panels from tbl_stack

Tags: r, kable, gtsummary

I am new to the `gtsummary` package and I want to try joining several tables together using the `tbl_stack` command.

```r
library(gtsummary)
gtsummary::tbl_stack(
  tbls = list(gtsummary::tbl_summary(mtcars["mpg"]),
              gtsummary::tbl_summary(mtcars["mpg"])), 
  group_header = c("Table 1", "Table 2"))
```

This creates a simple table where each table is it's own panel which is the behavior I want.

[image: tbl_stack]

However, I need to export my table to latex. To do this I am considering the `as_kable_extra` command which is causing my groups to become another column which is undesirable. Is it possible to retain the separate panels which I originally had?

[image: as_kable_extra]

Comment: This mid-row headers are a feature in gt that is not available in kableExtra