# Maintaining indent from `gtsummary` to `gt`?

Tags: r, latex, gtsummary, gt

I would like to convert my `gtsummary` table to a `gt` table and eventually to a latex while still maintaining the indent. What's an easy way to maintian the indentation?

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(gt)
    trial[c("trt", "age", "response", "grade")] %>%
    tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
    as_gt() |> 
    as_latex() |> 
    as.character() |> 
    cat()
```

output:

```latex
\setlength{\LTpost}{0mm}
\begin{longtable}{lcc}
\toprule
\textbf{Characteristic} & \textbf{Drug A}, N = 98\textsuperscript{\textit{1}} & \textbf{Drug B}, N = 102\textsuperscript{\textit{1}} \\ 
\midrule
Age & 46 (37, 59) & 48 (39, 56) \\ 
    Unknown & 7 & 4 \\ 
Tumor Response & 28 (29\%) & 33 (34\%) \\ 
    Unknown & 3 & 4 \\ 
Grade &  &  \\ 
    I & 35 (36\%) & 33 (32\%) \\ 
    II & 32 (33\%) & 36 (35\%) \\ 
    III & 31 (32\%) & 33 (32\%) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\textsuperscript{\textit{1}}Median (IQR); n (\%)\\
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid converting to raw latex, by creating the table in a quarto or rmarkdown document.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my goal is to export the table in latex.

Comment: This is latex. You can request quarto or R markdown to maintain the latex code as a separate file if you need it.

Comment: If you need the table in isolated latex code, perhaps try huxtable or kableExtra output?

Comment: huxtable and kableExtra have their own issues unfortunately, see my other question for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76932622/as-kable-extra-removes-panels-from-tbl-stack?noredirect=1#comment135622427_76932622

Comment: Oh haha, I didn't realize I was responding to you in both. In gtsummary, I used Unicode whitespace to make the indentations. But it's not the only way to indent with gt. You could look up other ways. But there's a chance the other versions only work in HTML? (It's been a long time since I've looked into other methods)